# linux/bounds.h not found while compiling source of my driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing drivers for my embedded device that has linux kernel version 2.6.32. In driver code, I am including `linux/modules.h` but on compiling, It gives me error `linux/bounds.h` not found.

I have downloaded kernel source from linux git repository. I have checked path settings. They are ok.

I checked my kernel source, there is no bounds.h file. So why my driver is expecting that. Error is coming due to including modules.h.

Comment: Are you talking about this file? http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h

Comment: yes, but I can't find it in my source code.

Comment: I did run find . -name "bounds.h" on root directory. No hit.

Comment: Did you run `make prepare`?

Comment: yeah, just got it. I did run make and its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I need to run `make` command, so that it can generate and link all necessary files.

Comment: Many thanks for this ancient tip , it's still quite useful! You might add, for those like me who are quite distracted and haven't compiled the kernel/drivers in decades, that you have to run `make` on the _top_ directory for the kernel source; also, `make prepare` might be more useful if one _only_ needs to compile the kernel modules, not the kernel itself...